# Is there a way to programatically force Windows to search for new WiFi nextworks?

Tags: c#, windows, wifi, simplewifi

I have a (C#) process which looks for the presence of an SSID, and connects if it appears.

As a process it works, but it does take a long time for the SSID to appear in the list.  IF I click on the WiFi icon in Windows to show available networks, it appears to then search and the SSID appears.  If I leave it for say 30-60 seconds, then it'll eventually appear.

So, is there a way to programatically do whatever it is that happens when you manually click on the WiFi icon in the taskbar?

Comment: At least tell us which API you are currently using to detect.

Comment: @Anders I'm using SimpleWifi on Nuget...but I'm not restricted to one API if something else will work better

Answer (score 0):

Windows must be interrogated about possible connections to refresh the list. You can do it this way (taken from [Update Wifi networks programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104707/update-wifi-networks-programmatically/65024992#65024992)):

```
var client = new WlanClient();
foreach (WlanInterface wlan in client.Interfaces)
   wlan.Scan();
```